# I try to find a API can instead of AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, task, communication

```
OSStatus myStatus = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(Autref, (const char *)[args UTF8String], myFlags,arguments, &communicationsPipe);
```

I want make my root app run other program and a communicationsPipe can communication this two program. But I find a warning:

> 'AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.7

So I want find API can instead of this. But I can not find it! So can anyone tell me about something?

Comment: Yes,I notice it.But it do not work!